# Adding ajax to Rails 3 form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery

I'm learning to program and got a form running in my Rails 3 app. Now I'm attempting to add ajax to the form so the page doesn't reload after submitting.

I've followed the numerous tutorials but can't quite seem to figure out how to bring it together. The form adds new `Objects` to the `Profile` through the following model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects
end

class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

**My form in `views/profiles/_object_form.html.erb`:**

```
<%= form_for(@object, :remote => true) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

**Where the form and its created objects are rendered in my `views/profiles/_about.html.erb`:**

```
<div id="newObjects">
  <%= render :partial => 'object_form' %>
</div>
<div id="objectList">
  <%= render :partial => 'object', :collection => @profile.objects, :locals => {:object_count => @profile.objects.length) %>
</div>
```

**In my `objects_controller.rb` I have the following create action:**

```
def create
  @object = Object.new(params[:object].merge(:author_id => current_user.id))
  respond_to do |format|
    if @object.save!
      format.html {redirect_to profile_path(@object.profile) }
      format.js { render }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @profile, :alert => 'Unable to add object' }
    end
  end
end
```

**In `views/objects/create.js.erb`:**

```
$('#objectList').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @profile.object)) %>");
```

So I have a form calling an action in another controller to which I want to add ajax. What happens at the moment is that I need to reload the profile to show the newly created object. What am I doing wrong?

**CLARIFICATION:** Other than the create action in the ObjectsController, I only reference @object once elsewhere. That's in the ProfilesController's show action:

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @superlative = @profile.superlatives.new`
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a full code snippet for your create action, but looks like you are trying to call render on an instance variable that doesn't exist...  `@profile` is never set in the `create` method in the `ObjectController`...

Perhaps you meant to type `$('#objectList').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @object)) %>");`

Also noticed that in your existing code you're making a call to `render @profile.object`, but the `Profile` class has a has_many relationship with your `Object` class, so if that was the right code, then you should type `render @profile.objects` (plural, not singular).

But I would think you would likely want the code I mentioned above, since you are appending onto the list of objects, not rendering the list again?

Comment: tvalent, you can't make a call to `$('#objectList').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @profile.object)) %>");` in your `create.js.erb` file because the ruby code in there is attempting to make a call on @profile, but @profile is undefined (nil).  Just because you have it set on the `show` action, doesn't mean it will carry over to the `create` action thread (even if it's ajax).  Pretty sure that's the problem.